# Wrong modulus result on PHP but right result on Python

Tags: php, python, math, modulus, fmod

I got the problem when operating this number on PHP

ex:

72 ** 79 % 3337

When i use

```
echo 72 ** 79 % 3337 // Result is int(0)
```

Then i try to split into this one

```
$num = number_format(72 ** 79, 0, '', '');
echo $num % 3337;   // Result is 1069
```

Then again i try using fmod() and bcmod()

```
$num = number_format(72 ** 79, 0, '', '');
echo fmod($num, 3337);        // Result is 2255
echo bcmod($num, 3337);       // Result is 2255
```

But, the result that i want is 285 and when using Python the answer is right.

Why does this happen? Any Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overflowing floating point resolution, so you need to do *all* the math with bcmath, including the exponentiation:

```
$num = bcpow(72, 79);
echo bcmod($num, 3337);
```

Output

```
285
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/j7d3N)